# Unable to install/load gazepath in R

Tags: r, dependencies, rstudio

I'm trying to install/load [Gazepath 1.3 GUI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gazepath/index.html) (software for eyetracking data analyses) in R, which hasn't been updated after 2020-02-09 (not supporting R 4+).

Since it successfully ran with R 3.6.3 previously, I'm using the same version of R in Windows 10 to find a way to run it with an older version of R, independent of the new versions. But I'm having issues with dependencies as below, and can't figure out what is causing the problem:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'bslib' ...
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.1.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/bslib'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bslib’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
* removing 'C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/scales'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'bslib', 'lifecycle' are not available for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4iqJK2\downloaded_packages’

> library ("gazepath")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gazepath’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘scales’
```

1. Tried installing dependencies (‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘htmltools’, ‘bslib’, ‘scales’, ‘shiny’) separately, but still getting the same errors.
2. Trying to use [Dateback Package](https://github.com/r-suzuki/dateback) to install dependencies which were available on a specific day, but getting the following error with R 4.2.1:

```
> dateback::install(pkgs = "gazepath", date = "2020-02-09")
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file = tmpf) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC63Vow\dateback\downloaded_packages/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in dateback::install(pkgs = "gazepath", date = "2020-02-09") : 
  An error occured during utils::install.packages.
Downloaded contents are in:
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC63Vow\dateback\downloaded_packages
```

After installing devtools with R 3.6.3:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

Also attached sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

Comment: with `R-4.2.1` , install.packages('gazepath', dependencies = TRUE) installs just fine. Close your 3.6.3. Restart your 4.2.1. then sessionInfo() for 4.2.1 to put above, then packageVersion('rlang')...

Comment: @ChaeyeonLim if you see a package list in the ordinary CRAN contributed package list then it should be installable on any OS for  which there are binaries. You might find that not all dependencies can be automatically installed because there is not a recursive search for them. So read the the error messages and act accordingly.

Comment: @Chris I can install Gazepath with R 4.2.1, but it's running (goes into an infinite loop) with R version 4+. That's why I've been trying to use R 3.6.3...

Comment: 'Goes into an infinite loop' with what data; that might make another useful question. But, as previously mentioned by @revans, it is nearly pointless to continue using R 3.6.3, so using gazepath in 4.2.1 - how can we confront the infinite loop.