# Unable to complete analyses with gazepath in R 4.2.1

Tags: r, dependencies

I'm trying to run analyses of two CSV data files with  [Gazepath 1.3 GUI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gazepath/index.html) (software for eye-tracking data analyses) in R 4.2.1.

I can install and load Gazepath GUI: it shows the progress of analyses as a pop-up window, but [it soon disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcxCc.png), and goes into [infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjyF3.png).

Below are the error messages I'm getting in R:

```
> library(gazepath)
The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning the sp package,
which was just loaded, will retire in October 2023.
Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports for details, especially
https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html.
It may be desirable to make the sf package available;
package maintainers should consider adding sf to Suggests:
The sp package is now running under evolution status 2
     (status 2 uses the sf package in place of rgdal)
Warning message:
package ‘gazepath’ was built under R version 4.2.3 
> GUI()
Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 4.2.3

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5287
Warning: package ‘jpeg’ was built under R version 4.2.2
Warning: package ‘scales’ was built under R version 4.2.2
Warning in rle(as.numeric(data[, trial])) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in rle(as.numeric(data[, trial])) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in rle(as.numeric(data[, trial])) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in gazepath(data = dataInput()[[i]], x1 = input$nameX, y1 = input$nameY,  :
  The trial index in the data frame was not unique, therefore trials are renamed to be unique and the old trial indx is stored in the data as TRIAL_OLD
Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator
  150: by
  149: gazepath
  145: eventReactiveValueFunc [C:\Users\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\gazepath\shiny\gpApp/server.R#149]
  101: gazepathInput
   98: renderTable [C:\Users\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\gazepath\shiny\gpApp/server.R#174]
   97: func
   84: renderFunc
   83: output$data
    2: shiny::runApp
    1: GUI
```

I tried using an older version of R as it successfully ran gazepath a few years ago. But I currently can't install and load gazepath with R 3.6.3 either ([previous post about running gazepath with R 3.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846242/unable-to-install-load-gazepath-in-r?noredirect=1#comment135487660_76846242)).

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76846242/unable-to-install-load-gazepath-in-r)?

Comment: @Limey n R 4.2.1, I can run gazepath but just cannot complete the analyses as it goes into an infinite loop.